# Finding cleaned/bounced email addresses for a MailChimp campaign or list

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'd like to automate the gathering of unsubscribe and cleaned email accounts for a given campaign.

In the API playground, I see all the methods available on the List entity.

**Unsubscribes**

I see that it's in the LIST API
`GET reports/xxxxxx/unsubscribed`

**Cleaned**

Where can I find the cleaned/bounced emails from a list or campaign? I know I can see the *count* of bounced in various places, but I'd like to find the email addresses that actually bounced, and the first and last names of the list member. Basically I'd like the API same as the 'export cleaned to csv' available on the website.

How can I use the MailChimp 3.0 API to do this?

[image: methods on a list]

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
GET lists/list_id/members?status=unsubscribed
```

to get unsubscribed users

```
GET lists/list_id/members?status=cleaned
```

to get cleaned/bounced users

Comment: This endpoint has bad performance, It will take approximately 10 seconds per 10.000 members in a list

Answer (score 1):

For the bounced emails in a specific campaign you need to do this:

```
GET /3.0/reports/campaign_id/email-activity
```

and iterate though all recipients in the campaign, manually locating actions with `type=bounce`.

```
    {
        "email_address": "xxx@example.com",
        "activity": [
            {
                "action": "bounce",
                "type": "hard",
                "timestamp": "2019-04-08T00:00:00+00:00"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Unfortunately MailChimp has very bad performance on this endpoint, approximately 25 seconds to return activity for a campaign with 500 recipients.

Answer (score 1):

Since soft bounce will not change `status` inside the list(audience), to get soft bounce email from the list without specific campaign, you can use

> GET lists/{list-id}/members/{subscriber_hash}/activity

This endpoint will only return for single email(contact), so you need to iterate through all email(contact) in the list.

Sample response:

```
"activity": [
        {
            "action": "bounce",
            "timestamp": "2019-05-01T23:02:26+00:00",
            "type": "soft",
            "campaign_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "title": "Xxxx Xxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "action": "sent",
            "timestamp": "2019-05-01T23:00:00+00:00",
            "type": "regular",
            "campaign_id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "title": "Xxxx Xxxxxxx"
        }
    ],
```