# Mailchimp API call to find all bounces from an Automation

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm attempting to write a Mailchimp API call that will detect all bounces (both hard and soft) from e-mails sent via an Automation.

It seems that it's fairly easy to do this for e-mails sent via a Campaign: I could run an E-mail Activity Report for a Campaign ID via GET: /reports/{campaign_id}/email-activity. I could then parse the results for emails['activity']['action'] to detect bounces.

However, there seems to be no similar report for Automations. Am I missing something, or is it impossible to detect Automation e-mail bounces via API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the version 3.0 of the MailChimp API does not expose such an endpoint.

You can only retrieve bounces for a List, not for an automation.

```
GET lists/list_id/members?status=cleaned
```

See also:

[Finding cleaned/bounced email addresses for a MailChimp campaign or list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959652/finding-cleaned-bounced-email-addresses-for-a-mailchimp-campaign-or-list/55589655#55589655)